# How dismiss PopupWindow whem click outside?

Tags: android, android-popupwindow

I use `PopupWindow` in my project.
And I can not dismiss it when touch display. I tried:

```
@Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                View popup = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.popup, null, false);
                final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popup, (int) DpiToPixel.calculateDpToPixel(150, getActivity()),
                        (int) DpiToPixel.calculateDpToPixel(150, getActivity()), true);
                popupWindow.showAtLocation(rootView, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                popup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        popupWindow.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);
                popupWindow.setTouchable(true);
                popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
                popupWindow.setTouchInterceptor(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Click!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        popupWindow.dismiss();
                        return true;
                    }
                });
            }
        }, 100L);
    }
```

But it's not working. I tried `popupWindow.setFocusable(true);` I tried `setBackgroundDrawable` on `PopupWindow` all not work. How can I dismiss this popup????????????

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Set a `BackgroundDrawable` and then set `setOutsideTouchable` parameter to true.

> setOutsideTouchable: Indicates whether the popup window will be
>   informed of touch events outside of its window.

```
popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable());
myPopupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);
```

Or try this:

```
myPopupWindow.setFocusable(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Move this statement to the end of your `run()` method:

```
popupWindow.showAtLocation(rootView, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
```

In other words, don't show the popup until *after* you have made all the calls configuring it.